# How do I sum up every 5th number instead of all numbers?

Tags: c#, loops, sum, numbers

I need some help with the for-loop. I'm trying to sum up every fifth number that I type in, instead it sums them all up. What do I have to change?

```
        int count = 0;
        double total = 0;

        Console.Write("Enter your number: ");
        int input = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        while (input != 0)
        {
            count++;
            for (count = 0; count <= 0; count += 5)
            {
                total = total + input;
            }
            Console.Write("Enter your number: ");
            input = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        Console.WriteLine("The sum of every +5 numbers is: {0}", total);
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: After 5 numbers, output the current sum and start over, is that what you want? Or do you want a rolling sum of the last 5 numbers?

Comment: Please post proper query. from your code seems like, your loop will iterate infinitely.

Comment: @Vishalmodi `while (input != 0)`. Try taking another look

Comment: you are confusing me, still not clear what you want to say

Comment: @Vishalmodi You are not correct. The loop will exit as soon as the user enters a `0` in the console.

Comment: @Martin, if use enter > 0, how while condition will stop?

Comment: @Vishalmodi Look at the code.  The `input` is captured before the end of the `while` loop.  It is not an infinite loop

Comment: Can't you see, once while loop executed, input value will not change until calculation not complete, and there is no changes inside while loop for input value.
just copy code and try to execute, and then let me know if i am wrong

Comment: @Vishalmodi I have run the code as part of my answer below.  It exits when the user enters 0.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200632/discussion-between-martin-and-vishal-modi).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you enter a list of numbers, and the 1st number and every five afterwards is added (so 1st, 6th, 11th, etc.):

```
int count = 0;
double total = 0;

Console.Write("Enter your number: ");
int input = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

while (input != 0)
{
    count++;
    if (count % 5 == 1)
        total = total + input;
    Console.Write("Enter your number: ");
    input = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}
Console.WriteLine("The sum of every +5 numbers is: {0}", total);
Console.ReadKey();
```

This works by using the modulo operator (`%`).  The modulo operator returns the **remainder** of a division operation involving the number you specify.

In the code `if (count % 5 == 1)`, the question is:

> Is the remainder of `count` divided by 5 equal to 1?

If so, it adds the number.  If not, it is skipped

The reason the remainder is one is because we want results 1, 6, 11, etc:

```
1 / 5 = remainder 1
6 / 5 = remainder 1
11 / 5 = remainder 1
```

If you change the modulo value to 0 it will return the results at position 5, 10, 15, etc.

Comment: I don't know who downvoted or why, but this helped me the most. At least I understand this as a beginner haha. I didn't think of using the if statement with the modulo operator since I'm quite new to this, but this was the tiny change that I needed. Thanks man!

Answer (score 1):

You could just store the numbers in a list and calculate it at the end:

```
var numbers = new List<int>();
Console.Write("Enter your number: ");
var input = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
while (input != 0)
{
    numbers.Add(input);
    input = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}
var total = numbers.Where((x, i) => (i + 1) % 5 == 0).Sum(); // i + 1 since indexes are 0-based.
Console.WriteLine("The sum of every +5 numbers is: {0}", total);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
double total = 0;
int passover = 4;
int input = 0;
do
{
  passover++;
  Console.Write("Enter your number: ");
  int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out input);
  if ( passover != 5 ) continue;
  passover = 1;
  total = total + input;
}
while ( input != 0 );
Console.WriteLine("The sum of every fifth numbers is: {0}", total);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to recover all the values ​​before making the sum, this code works:

`double total = 0;
        int input = -1;
        List<int> allInput = new List<int>();

        while (input != 0)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter your number: ");
            input = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            allInput.Add(input); 
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < allInput.Count()-1; i += 5)
        {
            total = total + allInput[i];
        }

        Console.WriteLine("The sum of every +5 numbers is: {0}", total);
        Console.ReadKey();`

Answer (score 0):

Your sample would go forever, because there is no break point in your loop. You should always put a break point in your loop, otherwise it'll loop indefinitely.

Here is what you need :

```
int total = 0;
int count = 0;

Console.Write("Enter your number: ");

while (true)
{
    int input = 0;

    bool isNumber = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out input);

    if (isNumber)
    {
        count++;

        if (count % 5 == 0)
            total += input;
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }

    Console.Write("Add another number or press enter to get the sum : ");
}

Console.WriteLine("The sum of every +5 numbers is: {0}", total);
Console.ReadKey();
```

So, you'll need first to put the user input inside a loop, and keep asking the user for adding another number until hits the condition where you close this loop. In the example, I decided to break the loop if the user typed anything not a number. but I told the user to press enter to get the some, to end the loop. For you, you'll need to translate that to your application breakpoint, how would you want the user to get the sum ?. Then, change the condition to your logic, so it breaks the loop and gets the sum.

another point is that `int.TryParse`. When you want to convert strings to numbers (int, long, decimal ..etc). You should always use `TryParse, this will verify the number, if the conversion failed, it'll return false. This way you can maintain the conversion and do something about it.

Comment: I haven't worked with booleans yet, so I don't completely understand. I do understand what you did with the modulo operator, which is exactly what I needed. Thanks man.